# Can an existentially quantified formula be a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I was wondering if a formula of the form $\exists xP(x)$, where $P(x)$ is any formula, can be a tautology. To me the domain could be empty, and therefore it is not satisfiable in every structure. But from an intuitive standpoint this is hard to grasp, especially if there are several quantifiers nested and implications involved, where the antecedent might then be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately this depends on exactly what semantics we use. Most presentations of first-order logic do **not** allow the domain to be empty; consequently, sentences like "$\exists x(x=x)$" are tautologies. On the other hand, if we do allow the empty domain, then no sentence of the form "$\exists xP$" can be a tautology since such a sentence cannot hold in the empty structure (similarly, no sentence of the form "$\forall x P$" can be a contradiction since such a sentence cannot *fail* in the empty structure).

Comment: Okay, then I assume that this is the case. The Idea of this not being possible really threw me off

Comment: @Alex Well you do have to be careful to check the convention of the text(s) you're using, especially if you're mixing multiple sources at once. But you've basically got the right idea: the only possible obstacle to an existential tautology is the admission of the empty structure, and on the other hand if we do admit the empty structure then that immediately kills the possibility of an existential tautology.